# Changing python headers directory for configure

Tags: linux, gnome

I'm trying to build `gnome-weather` using `jhbuild`, but running build process results in the following errors:

```
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
checking for headers required to compile python extensions... ./configure: line 14697: /usr/local/bin/python-config: No such file or directory
not found
configure: error: Python headers not found
*** Error during phase configure of gobject-introspection: ########## Error running ./autogen.sh --prefix /home/pgolinski/jhbuild/install  --disable-static --disable-gtk-doc  *** [7/36]

  [1] Rerun phase configure
  [2] Ignore error and continue to build
  [3] Give up on module
  [4] Start shell
  [5] Reload configuration
  [6] Go to phase "wipe directory and start over"
  [7] Go to phase "clean"
  [8] Go to phase "distclean"
```

Strangely the error says that Python headers were not found even though I have `python-devel` installed. I managed to find `python-config` in `usr/bin` so how to change its directory for configure? Or maybe the problem lies elsewhere? (I just want to build `gnome-weather`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what finally worked for me if someone struggles with something similair in future:

`PYTHON=/usr/bin/python jhbuild build gnome-weather`

Answer (score 1):

you can download the last version of gnome-weather here:
https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-weather/snapshot/gnome-weather-3.14.1.zip
and compile that with these command after unzip it:

- libtoolize
- aclocal
- autoheader
- autoconf
- automake --add-missing --foreign
- ./configure
- make && make install

this should work.8y3

Comment: During ./configure I get: "checking pkg-config is at least version 0.22... yes
./configure: line 13031: APPSTREAM_XML: command not found
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
./configure: line 13264: syntax error near unexpected token `1.35.9'
./configure: line 13264: `GOBJECT_INTROSPECTION_REQUIRE(1.35.9)'"

And then make doesn't work (output: makefile wasn't found). What shall I do now?

Comment: between the _automake..._ command and _./configure_ need to run `intltoolize --force` but the make process don't work well, there is a error into make file present in the data folder; I think that the makefile is not done well; alternatively try to compile the shell after executing this command `PYTHONPATH=$JHBUILD_PREFIX/lib64/python3.3/site-packages`